# How can I iterate the entries of an API?

Tags: python, api

I have this api : https://api.publicapis.org/entries

And I wat to iterate key **entries** of it. I tried as it follows :

```
r = requests.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries') 
    entries = [] #initializing the vector entries
    for i in entries: #iterating it
        return(i.text) #trying to print the entries
```

Then I received the following error : 
*TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.*

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: "The view function did not return a valid response." sounds like a web framework thing, not a Python thing. You'll need to share some more context with us here.

Answer (score 1):

For that particular API endpoint, you should be fine with

```
resp = requests.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries') 
resp.raise_for_status()  # raise exception on HTTP errors
entries = resp.json()["entries"]  # parse JSON, dig out the entries list
# ... do something with entries.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know how to  print it (entries) as a table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use json.loads to parse response text.

Let me add the full code.

```
import requests
import json
r = requests.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
entries = json.loads(r.text)['entries'] #initializing the vector entries
for i in entries: #iterating it
    API = i['API']
    Description = i['Description']
```